Proposition 2.6(b) in The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves - fiber cardinality is almost always equal to separable degree for a map of curves
Here is Proposition 2.6 from Silverman's The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves:

Proposition 2.6 Let $\phi: C_1 \longrightarrow C_2$ be a non-constant map of smooth curves.
(b) For all but finitely many $Q \in C_2$, $\# \phi^{-1}(Q) = \deg_s (\phi)$.

This can not be proved by Hartshorne's II 6.8 directly. I think it's relevant to the following question. $K(C_2) \subset K(C_1)$ and there is a separable closure $S$ of this extension. Then for any $B \subset K(C_2)$, it has an integral closure  $A \subset K(C_1)$. Then for a prime $p \subset B$,
$$
\# \{\mbox{prime } q \subset A \ | \ q \cap B = p\}
$$
has some relations with $[S : K(C_2)]$. What's the relation? And how to prove it?
The answer in Map of smooth curves and its separability degree almost solves the problem, except that $K(C_1)/K(C_2)$ may be inseparable.
I think that the integral closure $T/A$ in a purely inseparable extension has one-one correspondence in their prime ideals. Then the problem will be solved.

Yes, your final paragraph is almost correct. A purely inseparable morphism of schemes which is also projective with integral source and integral, normal, locally noetherian target has geometrically connected fibers, as proven here.
We can factor the extension of function fields $K(C_2)\subset K(C_1)$ as $K(C_2)\subset F \subset K(C_1)$ where $F$ is the separable closure of $K(C_2)$ in $K(C_1)$ so that $K(C_2)\subset F$ is separable and $F\subset K(C_1)$ is purely inseparable. Then $F$ corresponds to the function field of some curve $C$, and by the equivalence of categories between finitely generated fields of transcendence degree one over $K$ and regular projective curves over $K$ with dominant morphisms, we get morphisms $C_1 \to C \to C_2$ where $C_1\to C$ is purely inseparable and $C\to C_2$ is separable.
As these maps of curves are nonconstant, they are finite, and finite + geometrically connected fibers implies singleton fibers, so $C_1\to C$ is a homeomorphism. Then $C\to C_2$ is separable, so by the answer you link, we have that the fiber has cardinality generically equal to the separable degree of $C\to C_2$. Combining the two statements, we're done.
